# Match numbers or first letter before a character - regex

Tags: r, regex, tidyr

I am trying in R to match a specific pattern to make a separation into columns

Consider these examples of strings:

```
1-EXAMPLE
23-EXAMPLE2
A-EXAMPLE3
EXAMPLE-4
```

How can I write a regex to be used in `tidyr::extract` so that the separation happens as follows:

```
1   EXAMPLE
23  EXAMPLE2
A   EXAMPLE3
NA  EXAMPLE-4
```

I want to make a separation at the first `-` mark if before it there are only numbers, or if there is a single letter beforehand (as in the third case), but not if there more (as in example 4)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `case_when` to insert a character before we do `extract`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(col1 = case_when(str_detect(trimws(col1), '^([A-Z]|[0-9]+)\\s*-', 
       negate = TRUE) ~ str_c('-', col1), TRUE ~ trimws(col1))) %>% 
    extract(col1, into = c('col1', 'col2'), '^([A-Z]|\\d+)?\\s*-(.*)') %>% 
    mutate(col1 = na_if(col1, ''))
```

-output

```
col1      col2
1    1   EXAMPLE
2   23  EXAMPLE2
3    A  EXAMPLE3
4 <NA> EXAMPLE-4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("1-EXAMPLE", "23-EXAMPLE2", "A-EXAMPLE3", 
"EXAMPLE-4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: thank you! How could I add the possibility of having some whitespace before the "-"? I've tried ```"([A-Z\\s+]|\\d+\\s+)-(.*)"```, but it didn't work

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito does the update helps you

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito i would use `trimws` on the column first to remove that whitespace

Comment: but how would that work to remove white space before the "-", and not in the beginning of the string?

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito can you try the update.  I didn't test it because there was no example for that